# Hello, can somebody help me or any suggstion code how can I start in conditional for getting the range of specific range number

Tags: vb.net

can somebody help me or any suggstion code how can I start in conditional for getting the range of specific range number..

-Example there is textbox 1, 2, 3 and 4... 
-I inputed 1 in textbox1 and 5 in textbox2 
-in Textbox 3 I will input 3
-In textbox 4 will give the result and it will give me TRUE because 3 is in range of 1-5 but if I input 6 or 0 or any number that is not in the range, it will give me FALSE because it is not in the range of 1-5.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20448795/945456

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It is very hard to understand.

Comment: Sorry,,. Example scenario, there is a value of 1 and 10 then I want to get the range. If I inputed 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 It will return me "TRUE" because the sample value I inputed is in the range of      1-10. Otherwise or else it will give me "FALSE".

Comment: @user3221790: Take a look at my answer. I think I understood you correctly. If my answer helps, please mark my answer correct.

Comment: Also, for the future, don't put hello in the title. That doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to input the range in `TextBox1` and `TextBox2`, the number that needs to be evaluated in `TextBox3` and display the result in `TextBox4`.

Here is the code for that:

```
If CDbl(TextBox3.Text) > CDbl(TextBox1.Text) And _
        CDbl(TextBox3.Text) > CDbl(TextBox2.Text) Then
    TextBox4.Text = "TRUE"
Else
    TextBox4.Text = "FALSE"
End If
```

Comment: @user3221790: No Problem. Have fun coding.